# Changing button with text to icon for mobile displays

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have button:

```
          <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
          </div>
```

When I move to `xs` display I would like to change this `Send invitations` text to some search icon, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You need use css class [.hidden-xs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) & [.visible-xs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) for show & hide in responsive and non-responsive view. Try following code.

```
<div class="form-group pull-right">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search visible-xs"></i><span class="hidden-xs">Send invitation</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but read that `span` should not be inside `button` tag.

Comment: I think, will not create any issue for using span tag. You can see example in Opencart demo site. check it top bar links(My account, wishlist etc..with icon) code. http://demo.opencart.com/